postgresql: dynamically casting columns returned by a query
I have a DB in postgres with two tables, 'responses' and 'variables', like this:
responses



respondent_id
variable_name
response




01
name
susan


01
age
42


02
name
bob


02
age
13



variables



variable_name
type




name
text


age
integer



Note: The data in the 'response' column of the responses table is stored as text.
I'm trying to write a query that will "pivot" the data in the responses table from "long" to "wide" so that there is one row for each respondent_id, and a column for each of the variables in the 'variable_name' table... AND I want to convert the types of the columns returned according to the types listed in the variables table.  For instance, the 'age' column in the pivoted result should be cast as an integer.
The problem I'm running into is trying to use a "scalar subquery" to extract the type information from the variables table which can then be fed to a CAST expression.  Here is the query I've tried (which doesn't work):
SELECT
  respondent_id,
  CAST(
    max(case when variable_name = 'age' then response else null end) AS
    (SELECT variables.type FROM variables WHERE variable_name = 'age')
  ) AS 'age',
  CAST(
    max(case when variable_name = 'name' then response else null end) AS
    (SELECT variables.type FROM variables WHERE variable_name = 'name')
  ) AS 'name'
FROM responses GROUP BY respondent_id

This query throws a syntax error.  As best I can tell, this is because a scalar subquery cannot be used in the 'AS' part of CAST.  I think this is true because the following query works:
SELECT
  respondent_id,
  CAST(
    max(case when variable_name = 'age' then response else null end) AS
    integer
  ) AS 'age',
  CAST(
    max(case when variable_name = 'name' then response else null end) AS
    text
  ) AS 'name'
FROM responses GROUP BY respondent_id

How can I feed information from the variables table into my query so that the columns will be cast to the correct type?
One more note: Hardcoding the types in the CAST expressions is not an option for me.  What I've shown here is a greatly simplified example.  In the actual case I'm working with, there are about 1800 rows in the variables table, and I need a parameterized query that can create the pivoted-and-correctly-cast table for any arbitrary combination of those variables.
Thanks!

try unpivot as search term

Having 1800+ variables would make the resultset very 'wide' and sparsely populated. I would rather suggest a single aggregated JSON column (hopefully much more usable in the tier above) with the variable names as attributes.
So, first create a simple helper function
create or replace function jsonb_dyntype(v text, t text)
returns jsonb language sql as 
$$
select 
 case t
    when 'text'     then to_jsonb(v::text)
    when 'date'     then to_jsonb(v::date)
    when 'number'   then to_jsonb(v::numeric)
    when 'integer'  then to_jsonb(v::integer)
    when 'datetime' then to_jsonb(v::timestamp)
    -- other types 
 end
$$;

and then
select jsonb_object_agg(variable_name, jsonb_dyntype(response, type)) 
from responses r join variables v using (variable_name)
group by respondent_id;




jsonb_object_agg




{"age": 13, "name": "bob"}


{"age": 42, "name": "susan"}



DB Fiddle demo

that's beautiful!

PostgreSQL JSON support is beautiful

Yes. Very nice. If you don't have CREATE FUNCTION rights to PostgreSQL, DuckDB has json_transform() to map to different types (see addition to my answer below) and can be used with PostgreSQL.

You could also inline the function body case expression into the query

Using another language like R or Python can facilitate this. To illustrate, below is R code (using DuckDB, which is largely equivalent to PostgreSQL). You can even use it just to generate the SQL (seen as output from show_query() below).
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

db <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())

responses <- tribble(
    ~respondent_id, ~variable_name, ~response,
    01, "name", "susan",
    01, "age",  "42",
    02, "name", "bob",
    02, "age",  "13") |>
  copy_to(db, df = _, name = "responses", overwrite = TRUE)

variables <- tribble(
  ~variable_name, ~type,
  "name", "text",
  "age", "integer") |>
  copy_to(db, df = _, name = "variables", overwrite = TRUE)

ints <- 
  variables |> 
  filter(type == "integer") |> 
  select(variable_name) |> 
  pull()

result <-
  responses |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = respondent_id,
              names_from = "variable_name",
              values_from = "response") |>
  mutate(across(any_of(ints), as.integer))
  
result |>
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT respondent_id, CAST(age AS INTEGER) AS age, "name"
#> FROM (
#>   SELECT
#>     respondent_id,
#>     MAX(CASE WHEN (variable_name = 'age') THEN response END) AS age,
#>     MAX(CASE WHEN (variable_name = 'name') THEN response END) AS "name"
#>   FROM responses
#>   GROUP BY respondent_id
#> ) q01

Created on 2024-07-30 with reprex v2.1.1
JSON-based approach
Assuming the data are in PostgreSQL, can the JSON-based approach suggested by @Stefanov.sm be implemented using R (and DuckDB)?
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

responses <- tribble(
  ~respondent_id, ~variable_name, ~response,
  01, "name", "susan",
  01, "age",  "42",
  02, "name", "bob",
  02, "age",  "13") |>
  copy_to(pg, df = _, name = "responses", overwrite = TRUE,
          temporary = FALSE)

variables <- tribble(
  ~variable_name, ~type,
  "name", "text",
  "age", "integer") |>
  copy_to(pg, df = _, name = "variables", overwrite = TRUE,
          temporary = FALSE)

dbDisconnect(pg)

db <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
rs <- dbExecute(db, "INSTALL json")
rs <- dbExecute(db, "LOAD json")

rs <- dbExecute(db, "INSTALL postgres")
rs <- dbExecute(db, "LOAD postgres")

rs <- dbExecute(db, "ATTACH '' AS pg (TYPE POSTGRES, READ_ONLY);")

variables <- tbl(db, Id("pg", "variables"))
#> Note: method with signature 'DBIConnection#Id' chosen for function 'dbExistsTable',
#>  target signature 'duckdb_connection#Id'.
#>  "duckdb_connection#ANY" would also be valid
responses <- tbl(db, Id("pg", "responses"))

type_map <-
  variables |>
  # filter(variable_name == "age") |>
  summarize(types = json_group_object(variable_name, type)) |>
  pull()

result <- 
  responses |>
  group_by(respondent_id) |>
  summarize(json = json_group_object(variable_name, response)) |>
  mutate(json = to_json(json_transform(json, !!type_map))) 

result
#> # Source:   SQL [2 x 2]
#> # Database: DuckDB v1.0.0 [root@Darwin 23.6.0:R 4.4.1/:memory:]
#>   respondent_id json                             
#>           <dbl> <chr>                            
#> 1             2 "{\"name\":\"bob\",\"age\":13}"  
#> 2             1 "{\"name\":\"susan\",\"age\":42}"

result |>
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT
#>   respondent_id,
#>   to_json(json_transform("json", '{"name":"text","age":"integer"}')) AS "json"
#> FROM (
#>   SELECT respondent_id, json_group_object(variable_name, response) AS "json"
#>   FROM pg.responses
#>   GROUP BY respondent_id
#> ) q01

Created on 2024-07-30 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks Ian! I think the more general principle you're pointing to is that I can use a scripting language to generate my query dynamically.

All the code above runs in the database. You can even add compute(..., temporary = FALSE) to create a permanent table with no data ever leaving the database (well, a little bit of data pulled in to create ints above).

Yep!  I realized that after I wrote the comment, so edited it!

Yes. The Ibis framework probably offers a way of doing this with Python if that's more familiar: https://ibis-project.org https://iangow.github.io/far_book/sql-primer.html
